# Laravel 5 conditional many to many sync()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a content model with many-to-many to categories and tags. 
Categories and tags are stored in the same table with a boolean `tag` flag:

```
category_id | name        | tag
1           | Products    | 0
2           | bestsellers | 1
```

My Content Model has conditional relationships so defined:

```
public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Foothing\Content\Z\Entities\Category\Eloquent\Category', 'content_content_categories', 'cid', 'tid')->where('tag', false);
}

public function tags() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Foothing\Content\Z\Entities\Category\Eloquent\Category', 'content_content_categories', 'cid', 'tid')->where('tag', true);
}
```

While the `tag` flag is working properly on read operations, i.e.

```
$categories = Content::find(1)->categories;
$tags= Content::find(1)->tags;
```

it is not working as expected in `sync` operations, infact the following code

```
$content->categories()->sync(1, 2, 3);
```

will sync the whole table, regardless of the `tag` flag: tags will be destroyed and my content will be related only to categories 1, 2, 3.

Is it there something bad with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

I've come across the same situation like you, I play the trick like

```
// the 1st sync will remove all the relationship to the category table
$content->categories()->sync([1, 2, 3]);
// the 2nd sync is to extends the relationship from the 1st
$content->tags()->syncWithoutDetaching([4, 5, 6]);
```

Both are from same table, that means the `id` should be different. This should work fine for the problem

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Content::find(1)->categories` or any other relations it gets called through `Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php` file `line 2732` where this method `getRelationshipFromMethod` is called & from the model e.g this returns `return $this->belongsToMany('Foothing\Content\Z\Entities\Category\Eloquent\Category', 'content_content_categories', 'cid', 'tid')->where('tag', false);` & then it calls `getResults` on the return & collects the data.

On the other hand when you call `$content->categories()` this is directly method accessing from your `Content` model class & in return it returns `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany` class instance.

So to achieve your purpose you have

```
$content->categories()->where('content_content_categories.tag', false)
        ->sync([1, 2, 3]);//for syncing categories

$content->tags()->where('content_content_categories.tag', true)
        ->sync([1, 2, 3]);//for syncing tags
```

Also don't forget sync method accepts array of ids or collection check here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/22c06c504067cc52787f9fc4b04de4e496442212/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L756

Comment: This doesn't seem to work mate, when i perform the sync() this delete query is executed: `delete from `content_content_categories` where `cid` = ? and `tid` in (?, ?, ?)`. As you can see there's no evidence of the tag field being used in criterias.

Comment: I think what i'm trying to do is not possible at all using sync() without changing the database structure, since the only table involved in the query is the pivot table, which has not the tag column information.